# Linux command: find a program name and run the programs

Tags: linux, command-line

How do I manage to find a program in a directory and subdirectories, then run the programs?

For example,

```
find . -type f -name "abc"
```

finds all abc executables and:

```
find . -type f -name "abc" | RUN "abc" -p (WRONG!!!)
```

runs the abc programs with one parameter "-p".

How can I achieve it?

Comment: or just do `-shutdown 0`, wait 10-20 years, and try again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways, each more catered towards a specific need. Welcome to the UNIX world.

This runs the commands through `nohup`:

```
find . -type f -name 'abc' | xargs -I '{}' nohup '{}' -p
```

**Explanation**:

`find .` look in the current directory and it subdirectories.

`-type f` look for a file.

`-name 'abc'` the filename should be exactly "abc" (case-sensitive).

`|` pipe the resulting list of files to another program.

`xargs` send the individual entries to another program.

`-I '{}'` in the following expression, substitute `'{}'` with the entry.

`nohup` this is the program that `xargs` will invoke multiple times, each time passing one of the `find` results as a parameter. This program is used to launch jobs that will run in the background and will not be interrupted if the current session disconnects. To let you check the results, the output of commands executed through `nohup` is by default appended to the file `nohup.out` in the current directory.

`'{}'` this is a placeholder and will be substituted with the `find` results.

`-p` this will be appended as an additional parameter.

Example: let's say you have one file called "abc" in the current folder, and another in a subfolder called "sub"; the commands that will be executed are:

```
nohup ./abc -p
nohup ./sub/abc -p
```

Note: it could be useful to run `xargs -p` as it will display each single command before executing it. Answering `y` will actually launch it, `n` will skip it (`find . -type f -name 'abc' | xargs -p -I '{}' nohup '{}' -p`).

**Or** using `sudo`:

```
find . -type f -name 'abc' | xargs -I '{}' sudo -u $USER '{}' -p
```

`sudo` executes a command and allows to choose the user it has to be run as. In this example, it uses the current user, whose name is found in the `$USER` environment variable.

**Or** using `bash` (or your favorite shell):

```
find . -type f -name 'abc' | xargs -p -I '{}' bash -c "'{}' -p"
```

Here the commands are passed to bash, but you can choose to run them with a different shell (if you have it installed, of course). Just substitute `bash` with your choice of `sh`, `csh`, `tcsh`, `ksh`, `zsh`...

**Or** using `parallel`:

```
find . -type f -name 'abc' | parallel --no-notice -I '{}' "'{}' -p"
```

`parallel` is usually not installed by default but it can be worth using; think of it as an enhanced `xargs` (it's written to work with the same options) that has the useful feature of being able to run the entries it receives instead of always needing to pass them to another program (at least, I wasn't able to get xargs to do that). As its name suggests, commands are by default run in parallel maximizing cpu/thread utilization. The `--no-notice` option hides the citation it always diplays until run with `--bibtex`.

**Or** with `at`:

```
find . -type f -name 'abc' | xargs -I '{}' echo '{}' -p | at now
```

`at` schedules a command to be run at the specified time; in this example `now` is used to run the commands immediately.

Comment: Could you give some explanation on the first command line: "find . -type f -name 'abc' | xargs -I '{}' nohup '{}' -p"  ?

Comment: the first command line returns the result  "nohup: appending output to `nohup.out'"

Comment: @MattElson The solution here runs all commands through nohup. That means all output are redirected to the file `nohup.out`. For a direct output on screen, please consider the commands I listed.

Comment: `nohup` is just one of the solutions: `sudo` outputs to the terminal, as do `bash` and `parallel` which I added later.

Answer (score 1):

```
find . -type f -name "abc" | xargs -I'{}' echo '{}' -p  | bash
```

or

```
find . -type f -name "abc" | sed 's/$/ -p/' | bash
```

Both commands first list the files that named "abc" before the first pipe. Between the first and second pipe, both command appends the parameter `-p` after each line. Finally, after the second pipe, these "abc" commands are sent to bash for execution.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/632310)

Comment: @Burgi How is it not?

Comment: You offer no explanation on what the commands do and it appears to be identical to the other answer here.

Comment: @Burgi Please point out which command is identical to the other answer.

Comment: This is actually a good answer, worth my upvote. I too had the feeling that the OP knows enough to not need much explanation, but then I added it at his request.

Answer (score 0):

I would simply run this:

```
find . -type f -iname 'abc' -executable -execdir '{}' -p \;
```

This will run all `abc` executable files sequentially, with `-p` argument each time.

[Details](https://linux.die.net/man/1/find):

- `.` Search in current folder and sub-folders
- `-type f` Files only
- `-iname abc` File name restriction (case **i**nsensitive)
- `-executable` Restrict to executable files
- `-execdir` *...* `\;` Execute a command *(exec)* for each matching file *(\;)*, with working directory set as the matching file folder *(dir)*

  - `'{}'` Placeholder replaced by matching executable file *(ex: "./abc")*
  - `-p` Argument given to executable file